# React ContextMenu and Draggable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, contextmenu, draggable

I am trying to make a Draggable component with custom context menu in ReactJS, using
`react-draggable` and `react-contextmenu` with no success.
I`ve had succeeded to make a button draggable but when I add the context menu it disables the draggable and only the contextmenu works.
I would love to combine them together somehow, thanks!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import {ContextMenu, ContextMenuTrigger} from 'react-contextmenu';

export default function DraggableButton() {
  const [deltaPosition, setDeltaPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });  

  const handleDrag = (e, ui) => {
  const { x, y } = deltaPosition;
  setDeltaPosition({
    x: x + ui.deltaX,
    y: y + ui.deltaY,
  });
 };  

return (
  <div>        
    <Draggable
      scale={1}
      onDrag={handleDrag}
      bounds="parent"
      defaultPosition={{ x: 40, y: 40 }}
      allowAnyClick={false}
    >
      <ContextMenuTrigger id='trigger' >
          <div className="w-24">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">
                  click me
              </button>
          </div>
      </ContextMenuTrigger>
    </Draggable>

    <ContextMenu id='trigger'>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </ContextMenu>
  </div>
 );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `Draggable` around `ContextMenuTrigger`:

```
<ContextMenuTrigger id='trigger'>
  <Draggable
      scale={1}
      onDrag={handleDrag}
      bounds="parent"
      defaultPosition={{ x: 40, y: 40 }}
      allowAnyClick={false}>
      <div className="w-24">
        <button className="btn btn-primary">click me</button>
      </div>
  </Draggable>
</ContextMenuTrigger>
```

Note: the context menu opens in a different location with this.

Leaving this here as it may help others.